# difference of two date in mysql examples

Tags: mysql

> in mysql

**date1 = 2014-07-05 14:00:00
date2 = 2014-07-06 13:00:00**
**

- Total day : 2

**

Comment: The difference is 23 hours. How are you expecting to get a result of 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the mysql function `DATEDIFF(date1,date2)`

Where date1 and date2 are valid date or date/time expressions.

Example:

The following SELECT statement:

`SELECT DATEDIFF('2008-11-30','2008-11-29') AS DiffDate`

will result in this:

`DiffDate`

`1`

Comment: check in date = 2014-07-06 12:00:00 <br>
check out date = 2014-07-07 14:00:00<br> Hotel ruls if clint stay in more the 24 hours than its total day 2...